# Jade - Loading templates from different directories

Tags: templates, node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to work on Peepcode's Node.js Full Stack videos and it seems they're using an older version of express/jade. No mention of using block/extends to render layouts.

The setup used in the app is to have a /views/layout.jade file that loads for all sub-apps. The sub-apps' views are located in /apps//views.

My server.js seems pretty standard. Express is version 3.0.0rc1

```
require('coffee-script');

var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

require('./apps/authentication/routes')(app)

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

My routes file for the sub-app is in /apps/authentication/routes

routes.coffee

```
routes = (app) ->

  app.get "/login", (req,res) ->
    res.render "#{__dirname}/views/login",
      title: "Login"
      stylesheet: 'login'

module.exports = routes
```

The view I intend on rendering for this.

login.jade

```
extends layout

block content
  form(action='/sessions', method='post')
    label
      | Username
      input(type='text', name='user')
    label
      | Password 
      input(type='password', name='password)
    input(type='submit', name='Submit')
```

And Finally the layout.

```
doctype 5
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/#{stylesheet}.css')
  body
    block content
```

Going to localhost:3000/login renders this:

Express
500 Error: /Users/StevenNunez/code/HotPie/apps/authentication/views/login.jade:1 > 1| extends layout 2| 3| block content 4| form(action='/sessions', method='post') ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/StevenNunez/code/HotPie/apps/authentication/views/layout.jade'

My folder structure:

```
.
├── '
├── apps
│   └── authentication
│       ├── routes.coffee
│       └── views
│           └── login.jade
├── package.json
├── public
├── server.js
└── views
    ├── index.jade
    └── layout.jade
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like I had to just give the relative path in the `extends` call.

```
extends ../../../views/layout

block content
  form(action='/sessions', method='post')
    label
      | Username
      input(type='text', name='user')
    label
      | Password
      input(type='password', name='password')
    input(type='submit', name='Submit')
```

I didn't have to set `app.set('view options',{layout:false});`

Comment: ok... it works fine... but set the app because is the right way to work with the extends method

Comment: I'm working through the same tutorial and came across the same problem. For some reason I'm not comfortable using 'extends ../../../views/layout'. Is there an alternative to this?

Comment: To avoid `../../../views/layout` you can set jade's `basedir` config variable: `app.locals.basedir = __dirname + '/views';` and after that you should use 'absolute' (absolute from basedir) paths in your views, eg: `extends /layout`

Comment: Thanks had a problem. this solution fixed it.

Comment: I'm still not able to pass locals into the block using this solution.

Answer (score 6):

You can use variable `__dirname` to connect views from other directories.

Example:

```
app.get('/otherurl/' , (req, res) => { 
  res.render(`${__dirname}/../other_project/views/index`) 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use two methods of rendering...
The first layout that extends the layout and the second is block content.
When using a layout you are extending automatically the layout file in the folder of `login.jade`.

It isn't necessary to use `extends` and you can't use `block` sentence, but if you want to use `extends` you have to disable layout.

Add this to the app:

```
app.set('view options',{layout:false});
```

after

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

and extend the files like layout extends:

**layout.jade**

```jade
doctype 5
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/#{stylesheet}.css')
  body
    block content
```

**login.jade**

```jade
extends layout

block content
  form(action='/sessions', method='post')
    label
      | Username
      input(type='text', name='user')
    label
      | Password 
      input(type='password', name='password)
    input(type='submit', name='Submit')
```

The login file has to be in the same dir. If you want to call other layout you can use the dir like this:

```
appDirectory
  views
    layout
  otherViews
    login
```

**login.jade**

```jade
extends ../views/layout    
block content
  form(action='/sessions', method='post')
    label
      | Username
      input(type='text', name='user')
    label
      | Password 
      input(type='password', name='password)
    input(type='submit', name='Submit')
```

Comment: Thanks for this. What is the "right" method or rendering? Since I'm just getting into node/express/jade I want to try and follow the conventions set out by the community.