# Loading Jade templates in various directories?

Tags: node.js, pug, express

I am having trouble getting the results from [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675453/jade-loading-templates-from-different-directories) to work. I am just trying to create more modular blocks of code, and want to put the routes and views all together. I need a sanity check on this one.

I can't get the route to pickup the Jade file using relative paths (and I dislike the relative paths): `Error: Failed to lookup view "../test/app"`. Please help :)

Github: https://github.com/franklovecchio/stackoverflow-13770206

Folder structure:

```
    .
    │
    ├── package.json
    ├── public
    │   └── lib
    │       └── login
    │           ├── 0.0.1
    │           │   └── routes.coffee
    │           └── test
    │               └── app.jade 
    ├── server.coffee
    └── views
        └── layout.jade
```

**server.coffee**

```
express = require('express')
http = require('http')
path = require('path')

app = express()

app.configure () ->
  app.set 'port', process.env.PORT or 3000 # Give us the ability to specify port through command-line or external process.

  app.set 'view options', 
    layout: false

  app.set 'view engine', 'jade'

  app.use express.favicon() # auto-gen
  app.use express.logger('dev') # auto-gen
  app.use express.bodyParser() # auto-gen
  app.use express.methodOverride() # auto-gen

  # Required by session() middleware
  # Pass the secret for signed cookies
  app.use express.cookieParser('The Stay Puft Marshmallow Man')

  app.use app.router

  app.use express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')) # Serve static assets.

app.configure 'development', ->
  app.use express.errorHandler()
  app.use require('readymade').middleware(root: '/public') # Make .coffee/.less serve as compiled .js/.css files.

# Routes

# ======================  Login ======================  # 
login = require './public/lib/login/0.0.1/routes'
app.get '/', login.view
# ====================== /Login ======================  # 

http.createServer(app).listen app.get('port'), ->
  console.log 'Express server listening on port: ' + app.get('port')
```

**routes.coffee**

```
exports.view = (req, res) ->

  res.render '../test/app'
```

**app.jade**

```
extends ../../../../views/layout

p login
```

**layout.jade**

```
doctype 5
html
  head
    title My title
    block head
  body
    #content
      block content
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "description": "modular",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express":"3.0.4",
    "less":"",
    "jade":"",
    "markitup":"",
    "readymade": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could put all the files in some github repository or something. It would be nice to just fork and get working rather than copy pasting each and every file.

Comment: Sure! Here is the repo: https://github.com/franklovecchio/stackoverflow-13770206

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with `public` directory being your static file serving directory. Remove the following lines from your `server.coffee` and it will work just fine.

```js
app.use express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')) # Serve static assets.
```

Alternatively, put your code and views outside the `public` directory.

Answer (score 0):

routes.coffee

```
exports.view = (req, res) ->
  res.render __dirname + '../test/app'
```